# Can I "return early" inside a Runnable?

Tags: kotlin

Inside a `Runnable` block, I want to do some "guard block", like so:

```
var condition: String? = null
Runnable {
    if (condition == null) return
    // do something
}
```

but compiler says "return is not allowed here"??

Comment: how about `break`? :) sorry I don't use java 11. edit: Just saw the java tag get removed, I don't know kotlin either.

Comment: Have you tried `return@Runnable`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you! `return@Runnable` works and I feel so dumb now... I searched before asking but I guess my wording wasn't good. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can make this work:

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a "qualified return" as discussed [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#returning-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression). That's also what IntelliJ (AndroidStudio as well I guess) suggests:
[image]

As an alternative, you can define your `Runnable` as an anonymous class which enables you to use ordinary `return` statements:

```
 object: Runnable {
     override fun run() {
         if (condition == null) return
         // do something
     }
 }
```

IntelliJ will now suggest to transform this `object` to a lambda which will result in the exact same thing with a qualified `return`:

```
Runnable {
    if (condition == null) return@Runnable
    // do something
}
```

PS: No need to feel dumb! I suppose you would have found it easily with the right wording. It's good to know what `Runnable {}` is here. It's basically a lambda which is based on [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) (works with Java types with a single abstract method)

Comment: Thanks! It looks like IntelliJ is a lot better. Android Studio literally says "return is not allowed here" without giving suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on s1m0nw1's answer, using `return@Runnable` is correct.

`@Runnable` is, in this case, defining what you return. It also works with loops, but also methods. Here's an example with loops:

```
fun test(){
    one@for(i in 0..100){
        two@for(j in 0..i){
            if(j == 20){
                break;//this breaks two
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This example breaks the second when j == 20. If you want to break the outer loop when j is 20 (this might not be the best example, but you still get the general idea), you'd use `break@one`. For loops, this only works if you explicitly declare a label.

You basically have to specify what you want to break/return/continue (depending on what you use) in some cases. Returning from a regular method, or breaking a single loop doesn't need explicit labeling, but if you use lambda, or want to break outer loops, you'd target those using `[return/break/continue]@LabelMethodClassOrInterfaceName`.

In the example I added, if you want to return instead of break, you could use `return@test`. However, it's slightly pointless since `return` in that context implies from the method.

With this type of lambda, you're forced to use `return@InterfaceName`. `InterfaceName` is replaced with whatever interface you're using (in this case Runnable).

Or you could of course get IntelliJ to auto-complete it for you.